docker laravel mysql permission denied
I am dockerizing my laravel application but I am getting this error
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = testdb and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:

    # PHP Service
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            target: php
            args:
                - APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"
        environment:
            - APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"
            - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - database
    database:
        image: mysql:8.2
        ports:
            -   3306:3306
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

    volumes:
        db-data: ~

Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2 as php

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y unzip libpq-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bcmath

#RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
#    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
#    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .

COPY --from=composer:2.7.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

ENV PORT=8000
ENTRYPOINT [ "./docker/entrypoint.sh" ]

.env
APP_NAME=ArtisanOga
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:3Xsn8ZJVdxfgfg1+e6CqdWWIX/SNGW49T7AL4N6C73E=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret


I suggest that you adapt your docker-compose.yml so that the PHP service waits for the database to be ready to accept connections. You can do this by adding a health check to the database service and then making the php service depend on the database being marked as "healthy".
For the php service I have also set the MYSQL_PWD environment variable, which will be used for the database connection.
version: "3.9"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      target: php
      args:
          - APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"
    environment:
      - APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"
      - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
      - MYSQL_PWD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy

  database:
    image: mysql:8.2
    ports:
      -   3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
    db-data: ~

I'm not sure what your entrypoint.sh contains, but with the following I was able to get a reliable connection to the database.
#!/bin/bash

mysql -h database -u root -e 'select 1;'

There is no need for a password now because it's coming from the MYSQL_PWD environment variable.

But I want to define my own password

Yes, and that's done via your .env file. The contents of the .env file are used to set the environment variables for Docker Compose. And your docker-compose.yml file is then passing those environment variables on to the containers. If you look at the php service in my YML file you'll see that DB_PASSWORD from the environment is being used to define MYSQL_PWD in the container.
But you do not have to do this. I don't know that your entrypoint.sh does. My setup based on simple entrypoint.sh I provided. If you want specific solution then please add entrypoint.sh to question.
